# ARC "It is not safe to remove an unused autorelease message"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

When transitioning to ARC, I got the following compiler error: "It is not safe to remove an unused autorelease message".

If I simply remove the autorelease message, obj will be immediately deallocated at the end of getAutoreleasedObj, which will cause a crash in printObj. So How do I handle the autoreleased object, and convert the following code to ARC?

```
- (MyClass *) getAutoreleasedObj {
    MyClass *obj = [[MyClass alloc] init];
    [obj autorelease];
    return obj;
}

- (void) printObj {
NSLog(@"%@", [self getAutoreleasedObj];
}
```

Comment: You do not need `autorelease` in ARC iirc.

Comment: @LoganSerman Then at the end of getAutoreleasedObj, obj is already released, how can I use it in printObj?

Comment: What do you mean it is already released? ARC handles all releasing for you. It will release it whenever it needs to be released, so you don't have to worry about it. Read under "ARC Overview": https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What I've been confused by is, according to the link you gave me, obj's default qualifier is __strong, which will be sent a release message at the end of return call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to autorelease it, because it is returned from a function, ARC will implicitly make it `__autoreleasing` and release it for you.

This code:

```
-(id) getAutoReleasedObject
{
    __autoreleasing MyClass *obj = [MyClass new];
    return obj;
}
```

Compiles to this:

```
-(id) getAutoReleasedObject 
{
    MyClass *obj = [MyClass new]; 
    return [obj autorelease];
}
```

Comment: What if I drop the __autoreleasing? I tested it out, seems that dropping __autoreleasing won't cause an issue.

Comment: Oh I see, ARC is smart enough to add __autoreleasing instead of __strong.

Comment: @lichen19853 correct. ARC adds __autoreleasing to objects returned from a function, unless specified otherwise with a __attribute

Answer (score 3):

You have to remove the call to `autorelease`:

```
- (MyClass *) getAutoreleasedObj {
    MyClass *obj = [[MyClass alloc] init];
    // [obj autorelease];
    return obj;
}
```

The method `printObj` is now equivalent to the following:

```
- (void) printObj {
    MyClass *obj = [self getAutoreleasedObj];
    // At his point there is a reference to obj
    NSLog(@"%@", obj);
    // There are no references to obj now, ARC will take care of it. 
}
```

What I mean is that a valid reference to `obj` will be passed to `NSLog`, after that, there will be no other reference to `obj`.

Comment: Do we need a __autoreleasing before MyClass? According to Richard's answer, it is needed.

Comment: No. As he said, that will be added implicitly. You don't have to add it yourself.

Comment: My understanding is that if we don't specify the variable qualifier, ARC will make it default to __strong and cause a crash. Hmm, seems that I was wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You said:

> If I simply remove the autorelease message, obj will be immediately deallocated at the end of getAutoreleasedObj

That is incorrect.  Because the name of your method (`getAutoreleasedObj`) does not fit the alloc/init/copy/mutableCopy/new pattern, ARC automatically assumes that you want `obj` to be autoreleased.

You do not drain any autorelease pool at the end of `getAutoreleasedObj`, so `obj` won't be released.

Some autorelease pool is active when your code runs.  If you haven't manually set up an autorelease pool, then the active pool is the one set up by Cocoa's run loop.  That pool is drained at the end of each pass through the run loop.

So, unless you have set up your own pool somewhere, the object you create in `getAutoreleasedObj` will survive until the end of the current iteration of the run loop.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry can only make one comment the accepted one, but I voted up your answer.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned,

You do not need `autorelease` in ARC. ARC will handle releasing everything for you, so you don't have to worry about it. Under "ARC Overview":

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

ARC identifies your method family to determine when to insert a release.
Methods that start with init, copy, mutableCopy, new belongs to "init" family. ARC inserts a release in the calling method. In most cases, you don't have to return a auto-released object from a method. ARC intelligently inserts release/retains for you. You can override this behavior by decorating your method with NS_RETURNS_RETAINED/NS_RETURNS_NON_RETAINED

The only case where you need autorelease is when you return data by a write back pointer. In your case, you can safely remove the autorelease call.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to this, which has nothing really to do with ARC, and is actually about the transitioning process and the rewriter for converting to ARC, is to change the last two lines of the function from:

```
[obj autorelease];
return obj;
```

to

```
return [obj autorelease];
```

The ARC conversion rewriter does not allow [x autorelease] by itself, as it considers it dangerous if x is no longer referenced.  So you basically just have to ensure you use the return value from [x autorelease], easily done in the OPs case.